# How do I get vim to work at 256 colors in iTerm?

Tags: macos, terminal, color, iterm

I just got a new iMac, and installed iTerm (0.10).
On my last laptop 256 color mode worked fine, but I'm having trouble getting this to work on my new Mac.

I copied over all the settings, `set $TERM` to `xterm-256color`, but no dice.

I changed my `.vimrc` to the absolute minimum to try this out:

```
set t_Co=256
syntax on
```

Tried multiple colorschemes, too.

Comment: This SO question suggests using `let t_Co=256`, not set. Any results? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761770/iterm-vim-colorscheme-not-working

Comment: Also might try this article: http://jimlund.org/blog/?p=130

Comment: iTerm2 has the advantage of developer support for these kinds of issues. http://sites.google.com/site/iterm2home/

Comment: I just installed iTerm2 this afternoon, and it's excellent, Much closer to Terminal.app in it's cleanness, but with the extra functionality of iTerm, plus a few extra features of it's own.  GLTerminal is also a lot of fun, but thin on extra features ;)

Comment: FYI, in Lion, Terminal supports 256 colors and has a number of other enhancements. It may be worth taking a look to see whether iTerm2 still offers something you specifically want that Terminal doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so...

I just started vim again, and colors where there. Since then I did make a changehowever, I installed XCode. This is the only thing I did change, so there must be something in there that fixes this.

Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Prior to Mac OS X Lion 10.7, the terminfo files for xterm-256color and some others were part of the Xcode install instead of the regular system install. In Lion, they are now part of the system install.